# Recharts v2: breaking changes from v1.8x

Tags: migration, recharts

I'm jumping into a project that uses recharts v1.8x. I would like to upgrade that to v2.x.x, but I haven't found any migration guide/breaking changes list anywhere.

Does anyone have/know of a list of breaking changes between them (IE compatibility isn't needed).

-Jukka

Comment: Wondering the same thing, haven't found any by googling.

Comment: [As late as Dec 2020 there was apparently no migration guide and no plan to create one](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2333); I don't see any updates on that post, unfortunately.